# A polynomial whose galois group is D_8

Tags: galois-theory

I need to construct such a polynomial, and more generally: given a group G, how can it be realized as a galois group?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem

Comment: As Konstantin says, this problem is very difficult in general. But it is doable for certain subgroups of $S_n$ for low $n$. Do you know how to compute Galois groups of cubics and quartics? As for your example, I think $x^4-2x^2-2$ works.

Comment: Not over the complex numbers. Dharam: If you write $D_8$, do you mean the dihedral group with 8, or with 16 elements?

Comment: This question has also been asked in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188296/a-polynomial-whose-galois-group-is-d-8

Comment: @J.C.Ottem: your example works for what is usually denoted by $D_4$ (symmetries of the square), not $D_8$, but then again, as @René suggests, the OP might have meant that. For $D_8$ the story is more tricky, in particular, there is no "generic polynomial construction" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_polynomial).

Comment: Yes, it's not so clear which one me means here..

Comment: Personally, I believe that it should be acceptable to ask "basic" questions on mathoverflow rather than math.SE if the asker prefers more concise answers using higher-powered machinery, or if the question has been asked on math.SE without receiving a good answer. I personally would probably even consider acceptable a question that was asked simultaneously on both sites, if the asker linked the two questions and gave a good explanation for why they were posting simultaneously. However, since this question was cross-posted simultaneously with no explanation, I am voting to close.

Comment: @Dharam: do you mean over $\mathbb{Q}$ as ground field? You don't say in your question. 

Answer (score 7):

For the case that $D_8$ is interpreted to be with $16$ elements (which is the case according to OP on M.SE) an example is given by 
$$ x^8 - 3 x^5 - x^4 + 3x^3 +1 $$
This is a polynomial with minimal (in absolute value) discriminant with that Galois group.

For the other interpretation of $D_8$ a polynomial with minimal discriminat would be 
$$x^4 - x^3 -x^2 +x +1 $$

As said in the comments the general problem is difficult (indeed open even regarding existence, that is over the rationals, which I assume is the intention of the question).

The above polynomials and information are taken from the [database of Jürgen Klüners and Gunter Malle](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/home) 
where a great many examples and information can be found, presented in a nice way. 
So, for examples for specific not too large groups one migt well find a polynomial there, even if one wishes additional restrictions (on the siganture, say).

Comment: I didn't know of the database. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For Galois groups up through degree eight, you can easily provide an infinte number of examples by the function field extensions listed here:

[Some polynomials over Q(t) and their Galois groups](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000-69-230/S0025-5718-99-01160-6/S0025-5718-99-01160-6.pdf)

Comment: I had assumed OP meant over $\mathbb{Q}$, although I grant you that wasn't specified in the question. 

Comment: The point is, if you have F/Q(t) with Galois group G, specializing t to a value in Q leads to an extension K/Q with Galois group G in nearly all cases. Hence it's a sort of machine for cranking out endless examples. It is particularly nice if F contains no algebraic extension of Q, as then the examples your machine cranks out don't share a common extension of Q.


Answer (score 2):

Over $\Bbb Q$, F. Seidelmann, in
"Die Gesamtheit der kubischen und biquadratischen Gleichungen mit Affekt bei beliebigen Rationalitätsbereich, 
Math. Ann. 78, 230--233 (1917)",
gives the following parametric representation of degree $4$ equations with group $D_8$:
$$x^4-2(e^2f+g)x^2-4efx+[(e^2f-g)^2-f]=0$$
(with some restrictions on the parameters)